# Python - delete multiple list elements in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a simple dictionary structure in Python which is being used as a pseudo database. An example of six entries is shown below:

```
a={}
a['Name']   = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
a['Number'] = [1  ,2  ,3  ,4  ,5  ,6  ]
a['Sum']    = [2  ,1  ,4  ,3  ,6  ,5  ]
```

Each key in the dictionary refers to a specific field type e.g. Name, Number, Sum etc and the data stored against this key is a list of length n, where n is the number of entries. Note that the lists are all of length n. This set up allows me to easily access records for each entry, for example, to get the 3rd entry for all fields I can use:

```
a['Name'][2]
a['Number'][2]
a['Sum'][2]
```

Filling this structure is very easy using the dictionary append method. My question is about deleting entries. Suppose I want to remove one of the records but leave the rest in the same dictionary / lists, how do I do this? By this I mean, how could I remove the third entry such that the dictionary and lists are now:

```
a['Name']   = ['a','b','d','e','f']
a['Number'] = [1  ,2  ,4  ,5  ,6  ]
a['Sum']    = [2  ,1  ,3  ,6  ,5  ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is likely to be implemented in a loop somewhere in my code i.e. I'm looking to remove the ith entry as opposed to always the 3rd entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With that data structure, there's not much better you can do than

```
for v in a.values():
    del v[2]   # or v[n] in general
```

Comment: you should have written this as a function accepting `n`

Comment: Does this delete all the 3rd or nth entries in one go?

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the `del` functionality here seems to be the most simple method to delete items from your lists...

```
del a['Name'][nth-item]
```

Comment: I assume I could iterate over the keys eg 'Name' 'Number', 'Sum' and also the list elements eg 'n' to delete multiple entries?

Comment: You are correct :) ... just make sure when deleting items from a list by index that you iterate through the list backwards to maintain the correct indexing.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - I'd would have totally missed the backwards iterating!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider `pandas` for this task:

```
In [69]: import pandas as pd
In [70]: a
Out[70]: 
{'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
 'Number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 'Sum': [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]}

In [71]: df = pd.DataFrame(a).T

In [72]: df
Out[72]: 
        0  1  2  3  4  5
Name    a  b  c  d  e  f
Number  1  2  3  4  5  6
Sum     2  1  4  3  6  5

[3 rows x 6 columns]

In [73]: del df[2]

In [74]: df
Out[74]: 
        0  1  3  4  5
Name    a  b  d  e  f
Number  1  2  4  5  6
Sum     2  1  3  6  5

[3 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: A neat solution using pandas although I'm looking to stick to generic Python code ie not pandas

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little obscure, but i like the shortness:

```
# index to remove
n = 2

a = {k: v[:n] + v[(n + 1):] for k, v in a.items()}
```

As a function, as someone suggested:

```
   def del_idx(n):
       return {k: v[:n] + v[(n + 1):] for k, v in a.items()}
```

Edit: less lists.

```
a = {k: [i for ids, i in enumerate(v) if ids != n] for k, v in a.items()}
```

Comment: Not obscure, but not very efficient to create 3 new lists for each value in the dict.

Comment: You are right, i'm way too addicted to comprehension.

Comment: Your last version won't work properly if there are duplicate values in any of the lists

Comment: Fixed, but still ugly.